# SQL Server stored procedure and execute in VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is a bit old-contents to be discussed but I need someone who can explain me how to create stored procedure in SQL Server for returning a value from procedure, example:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE IDCUSTOMER = 'DS212';
```

Then I need the name of its customer and the address instead.

I need to make it as a stored procedure and show me how to execute it on VB.NET. Perhaps we assume that the name will be prompted to LABEL1.TEXT and the address will be prompted to LABEL2.TEXT.

I've improved this SQL-Server Stored Procedure Using return but I have nothing to return after I execute it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting_customer
            @custId varchar(10),
            @usr_id int
AS
BEGIN 
SET @usr_id = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(CUSTOMER.idCustomer,3, LEN(CUSTOMER.IDCUSTOMER))) FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(CUSTOMER.idCustomer,1,2) = @custId)
END
RETURN @usr_id
GO
```

This is my VB.NET

```
  conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("inserting_customer", conn)

        Try
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@custId", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters("@custId").Value = "YW"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usr_id", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@usr_id").Value = 0
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Finally
            If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
            If conn IsNot Nothing AndAlso conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
```

Comment: a bit explanation might help me so much rather than google it. I know its efforts but perhaps I'm looking for a simple code rather than complicated google provides :) Thank you before

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Supposing you have this sproc in sqlserver

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNameAddress(@custID nvarchar(10))
as
BEGIN
SELECT NAME,ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE IDCUSTOMER = @custID;
END
```

you call it and get the result in the standard way

```
' GetConnection is a method that creates and return the '
' SqlConnection used here according to your connection string'
Using cn = GetConnection()
   cn.Open()

   ' Create the command with the sproc name and add the parameter required'
   Dim cmd As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("GetNameAddress", cn)
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", "DS212")

   ' Ask the command to create an SqlDataReader on the result of the sproc'
   Using r = cmd.ExecuteReader()

       ' If the SqlDataReader.Read returns true then there is a customer with that ID'
       if r.Read() then

           ' Get the first and second field frm the reader'
           lblName.Text = r.GetString(0)
           lblAddress.Text = r.GetString(1)
       end if
   End Using
End using
```

Notice that this is the standard approach when you expect zero or one record returned by the sproc. If you have more than one record then you use a while loop over the SqlDataReader.Read method and you should provide the controls where store the returned records.

Comment: Respect this answer! Thank you very much for including the syntax and the clear explanation pal! God bless you ... LOVE THIS