# How can I avoid duplicates insert of records from datagridview to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 where I have a table `CT11`. What I want is to stop inserting duplicates records in the table using cellendedit event. How can I do it because I am getting duplicates of records?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit

    For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows

        If cmbexam.Text = "CAT 1" Then

            sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO CT11 (Admno, Name, Score) VALUES ('" & row.Cells(0).Value & "','" & row.Cells(1).Value & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "')"
            ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: With a UNIQUE key.

Comment: Please research SQL Injection and learn to use parameters with your SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn how to use SQL Command
[How to use parameters "@" in an SQL command in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139791/how-to-use-parameters-in-an-sql-command-in-vb)

If you want the database to validate your entry then learn how to use Stored Procedure
https://mostafaelmasry.com/2015/10/03/creating-system-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008-r2/

In Stored Procedure add a condition that will check your entry ex;

```
SELECT @record = COUNT(1) FROM CT11 
WHERE Admno = @Admno AND Name = @Name AND Score = @Score;

IF @record = 0
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO CT11 (Admno, Name, Score) VALUES (@Admno, @Name, @Score);
   END
```

In VB

```
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
    If cmbexam.Text = "CAT 1" Then
        MyCommand = New SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", dbConn)
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Admno", row.Cells(0).Value)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells(1).Value)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", row.Cells(2).Value)
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Next
```

Or follow this thread: [SQL Server stored procedure and execute in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373301/sql-server-stored-procedure-and-execute-in-vb-net)

Or you can use VB to validate the values by executing a select statement and check if there a record or not.